# Compose Bottomsheet design collapse when keyboard opened

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When keyboard opens when bottomsheet visible, it pulls the modal bottom sheet up and hence the parent view is visible from which bottomsheet opens,(ie, in between bottomsheet bottom border and keyboard - Parent view is visible), is there any way to make sure the bottomsheeet border fits just above the keyborad

```
 ModalBottomSheet(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Transparent, shape = RectangleShape)
        .fillMaxHeight(1f),
    sheetState = state, dragHandle = { false },
    onDismissRequest = {
        onDismiss(false)
    },
    scrimColor = Color.Transparent,
    windowInsets = WindowInsets.ime
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 50.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 25.dp, end = 25.dp, top = 25.dp)
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.TopCenter)
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = title,
                    style = primaryCtaBtnTextStyle.copy(
                        fontSize = 24.sp,
                        color = fi_black_shade
                    )
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(15.dp))
                LazyColumn(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 20.dp)
                ) {
                    itemsIndexed(items = items) { index, item ->
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                                .padding(top = 5.dp)
                                .clickable(indication = null,
                                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }) { 

 ////////////////////////////

            }

        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

        if(showError.value) {
            Text(
                text = "Please select your occupation",
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 25.dp),
                style = needHelpTextStyle.copy(color = BlazeOrange))

        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp))

        OutlinedTextField(value = "fdfdf", onValueChange = {

        })

        PrimaryCTABtn(
            onclick = {
                //selectedButtonState.value?.let { onSelected(it) }
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentSize()
                .padding(start = 40.dp, end = 40.dp)
            ,
            buttonText = "SELECT"
        )

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add keyboardAwarePadding to your modifier

```
   ModalBottomSheet(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Transparent, shape = RectangleShape)
        .fillMaxHeight(1f)
        .keyboardAwarePadding(),
    sheetState = state,
    dragHandle = { false },
    onDismissRequest = {
        onDismiss(false)
    },
    scrimColor = Color.Transparent,
    windowInsets = WindowInsets.ime
) {
    
}
```

Comment: Tried this already, still the same result